# Replace <NA> values with empty strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created dataframe which looks like this. which is of Nullable integer data type.

```
arr = pd.array([1, 2, None,4], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
```

output:

```
[1, 2, <NA>,4]
```

I want to replace `<NA>` values with an empty string. I have tried different replace methods nothing worked. is there a way that I can achieve this.

I want my output to look like this.

```
[1, 2, ,4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a string in an `<IntegerArray>`. You must convert the array to the `object` type before the replacement:

```
arr_as_object = arr.astype(object)
arr_as_object[arr.isna()] = ' '
# array([1, 2, ' ', 4], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  replace with space

```
arr = np.where(arr.isna(),' ',arr)

array([1, 2, ' ', 4], dtype=object)
```